# Getting a url using ant in JBoss EAP AS 6.3

Tags: jboss

i have a simple ant task to get an url and save it to a file:

```
<target name="test_xhtml">
    <get verbose="on"
        dest="/tmp/test.xhtml"
        src="http://localhost:8080/forms/faces/test.xhtml?param=loremipsum" 
    />
</target>
```

The scripts returns:

```
test_xhtml:
      [get] Getting: http://localhost:8080/forms/faces/test.xhtml?param=loremipsum
      [get] To: C:/tmp/test.xhtml
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://localhost:8080/forms/faces/test.xhtml?param=loremipsum
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://localhost:8080/forms/faces/test.xhtml?param=loremipsum
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://localhost:8080/forms/faces/test.xhtml?param=loremipsum
      [get] Can't get http://localhost:8080/forms/faces/test.xhtml?param=loremipsum to C:\tmp\test.xhtml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 468 milliseconds
```

Well, the question is how i can get the url? (maybe some configuration in jboss 6.3 because http 505 means that jboss don't reconigse the http protocol used by ant: see [http spec#505](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.6)